# How can I change a Boolean value in a collection to the opposite of what it already is?

Tags: c#

I have a collection and I want to change the value of an item in the collection. Here's how I am doing it:

```
private ObservableCollection<Phrase> _phrases = 
   new ObservableCollection<Phrase>();

public ObservableCollection<Phrase> Phrases { 
   get => _phrases; 
   set => SetProperty(ref _phrases, value); 
}

var newState = 
   Phrases.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PhraseId == phraseId).F3 
   = !Phrases.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PhraseId == phraseId).F3;
```

Is there an easier way that I can do this with LINQ or is this the only way?

Comment: you're searching for the object twice, just do FirstOrDefault once and then do: myObj.F3 = ! myObj.F3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would avoid querying the collection twice

```
Phrase item = Phrases.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PhraseId == phraseId); 
if (item != null)
{
    item.F3 = !item.F3;
}
```